# How do a flexLayout auto width?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to make the flexlayout auto adjust it's width.

When I do not use flexlayout but only lable

```
    <Frame BackgroundColor="#5fb878" Padding="10" HasShadow="false" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1">                                        
        <Label Text="测试员013号" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize="18"/>                                      
</Frame>
```

Yes it auto fits the lable's size.but when I add the flexlayout it auto take the max width as it's width:

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="#5fb878" Padding="10" HasShadow="false" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <FlexLayout Direction="Row">
                                            <Label Text="测试员013号" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize="18"/>
                                        </FlexLayout>
                                    </Frame>
```

since I will add several views in the frame not only a lable.
Is there anyway to make the frame auto fit the total width of all the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you used Grid to display this `Frame` directly and it will make it take all the space of the second column. You can wrap it with an extra StackLayout to fix that:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Frame BackgroundColor="#5fb878" Padding="10" HasShadow="false" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <FlexLayout Direction="Row">
                    <Label Text="测试员013号" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize="18" />
                </FlexLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

However, I noticed that you only utilized the `FlexLayout`'s Direction feature, I think `StackLayout` may be a better choice:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#5fb878" Padding="10" HasShadow="false" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="测试员013号" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize="18" />
                <Label Text="second label"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage.Content>
```